# How many levels of interpretation/compilation are there in a computer?

Tags: java, c++, cpu-architecture

When we have an object file (compiled file of any program in c/c++ or any other language) does it contain op-codes which can be directly understood by processor or there are more levels of interpretation/compilation which generate the desired op codes for processor.
                           in the case of JVM, does it generate op-codes for real processor or it generate code for something intermediate.

Comment: You know, there is a fuzzy boundary between "document" and "program."  If you define a program as "data that controls the behavior of something else," then a text file would qualify as a program.  If you don't like that, consider "documents" in languages like Postscript and LaTeX.  And of course, we all know about "self-documenting code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and C++ are usually compiled to machine code, and yes, those opcodes can be directly understood by the processor.

But what's “directly”?

The processor can have several levels of internal interpretation. With one level of interpretation that's called [**microcode**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode). I'm not sure of terminology for two or more levels but you can google it.

Furthermore, the program might be executed on a (possibly hardware-assisted) simulation of the computer in question.

So there can be *any* number of  levels of interpretation before you reach the doer hardware.

---

AFAIK Java is still usually compiled to instructions for a virtual machine. However, those instructions are usually (or were usually) compiled to machine code on the fly, as the program was executed, called [**JIT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compilation, *Just In Time*. Also, <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode)</sup>reportedly, some IBM machines have direct support for the the Java virtual machine, able to execute at least some of the opcodes (more or less) directly.

Then there are a number of physical [**Java processors**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor), designed to execute Java bytecode directly.

---

<sup><sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode)</sup> I'm unable to find references with just quick googling. It may be that I've got the wrong impression from some article. Maybe some IBM mainframes are just optimized for execution of the Java virtual machine.</sup>

Comment: Directly in the sense that you place the object code in memory and processor goes through it , using fetch execute cycle.

Comment: First - there is no processor which understands all Java opcodes. Second, speaking about platform-dependent languages, object files do include bare machine code, but, usually, it couldn't be executed as is, usually because some information is just missing.

Comment: @VallyN: I think for the claim of "no processor" you would have to specify the JVM version that is currently not fully covered by any processor. Do you have a reference for the claim (I'm not very familiar with this stuff, it's very much a moving target)? Regarding C and C++ object files, I am not aware of *any* case where they can be executed as is, so the "usually" appears meaningless to me.

Comment: Some long long time ago... there was no need in linkers. Object files generated by compilers could be executed as is.

Comment: @VallyN: Re "Some long long time ago... there was no need in linkers. Object files generated by compilers could be executed as is.". That claim seems absurd, but while it's practically meaningless it's technically possible. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Any old or new assembler. For example MASM, TASM, FASM and others.

Comment: @VallyN: That's wrong. I've used both MASM and TASM.

Answer (score 2):

In the JVM there are many levels.

There is

- interpreted code which use machine code op code indirectly (C/C++ doesn't have this stage unless you add your own way to do this, as the JVM does)
- machine code, possibly CISC instructions.
- if you are running on a kernel virtual machine, some instructions can be modified by your KVM.
- the CPU can turn these into RISC instructions which are stored in its L0 instruction cache.

Comment: Most processors also support "software-implemented" instructions. When it finds unknown instruction, software interrupt can process it according to some rules you may program.

Comment: @VallyN this can be done to patch hardware bugs for example. +1